# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable in a spatial regression model

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, regression, spatial

I am doing a spatial lag model in order to find which variables are related to the dependent variable.

```
import libpysal as lps
# read the .dbf file from shapefile data
f = lps.io.open('data/lambeth_data2.dbf','r')
# Read into an array y
y = np.array(f.by_col['Mental hea'])
y.shape = (len(y),1)
# value for independent variables into a one dimmensional array X. 

X= []
X.append(f.by_col['Greenspace']) 
X.append(f.by_col['Imd score']) 
X.append(f.by_col['Population']) 
X.append(f.by_col['NUMPOINTS'])

X = np.array(X).T

w_queen2=Queen.from_shapefile('data/lambeth_data2.shp')

from spreg import ML_Lag
spat_lag2 = ML_Lag(y,X,w_queen2,name_y='Mental hea', 
                  name_x=['Greenspace','Imd score', 'Population','NUMPOINTS'],
                  name_w='w_queen', name_ds='lambeth_data')
print(spat_lag2.summary)
```

There are four independent variables in X.

But there is an error after running:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [145], in <module>
      1 from spreg import ML_Lag
----> 2 spat_lag2 = ML_Lag(y,X,w_queen2,name_y='Mental hea', 
      3                   name_x=['Greenspace','Imd score', 'Population','NUMPOINTS'],
      4                   name_w='w_queen', name_ds='lambeth_data')
      5 print(spat_lag2.summary)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/msda2021/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spreg/ml_lag.py:557, in ML_Lag.__init__(self, y, x, w, method, epsilon, vm, name_y, name_x, name_w, name_ds)
    555 set_warn(self, warn)
    556 method = method.upper()
--> 557 BaseML_Lag.__init__(
    558     self, y=y, x=x_constant, w=w, method=method, epsilon=epsilon)
    559 # increase by 1 to have correct aic and sc, include rho in count
    560 self.k += 1

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/msda2021/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spreg/ml_lag.py:235, in BaseML_Lag.__init__(self, y, x, w, method, epsilon)
    232     self = None
    233     return
--> 235 self.rho = res.x[0][0]
    237 # compute full log-likelihood, including constants
    238 ln2pi = np.log(2.0 * np.pi)

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

PS.
Before X and y are passed to ML_Lag,

X:

```
array([[  0.51,  23.57, 168.22,   2.  ],
       [  5.05,  32.47, 142.03,   0.  ],
       [  1.19,  22.23, 152.32,   2.  ],
       ...
       ...
       [  1.21,  19.84,  93.39,   4.  ]])
```

y:

```
array([[17.79],
       [24.97],
      ...
      ...
       [15.96]])
```

I don't know how to fix it, please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample of what your variables `y' and `X` look like prior to passing it to the `ML_Lag` instance?

Comment: You can't "fix it" without first understanding what is wrong and why.   The immediate cause is that `res.x` or `res_x[0]` is a scalar, that can't be indexed.  The challenge is to trace that `res.x` back through the `spreg` code to the parameters you provide.  Another approach is to look at the `ML_Lag` docs, and carefully compare what it expects with what you provide (actually provide, not what you guess!).  Quite possibly some argument array shape is wrong - 1d when it should be 2d or some such thing.

Comment: I've re-edited my posting to add an explanation of exactly what X and y are, can you help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: @whege I've re-edited my posting to add an explanation of exactly what X and y are, can you help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: The ML_Lag docs say `y` is expected to be a "nx1 array". I'm wondering if changing it to `y = array([17.79, 24.97.....15.96])` wouldn't fix this.